# Value '1' Not Valid for 'Index'

Tags: c#, minecraft, balloon-tip

This is the error I've been recieving when I attempt to run my program. (Excuse the Minecraft in the background, it's a key part of what I'm attempting to create)

[image: Error Recieved]

Here's the C# code that I was trying to execute

```
    int oldCount;

    string RecentPlayer;
    string val;

    public void SetBalloonTip()
    {

        NewPlayerMessage.BalloonTipTitle = "A Player Has Joined!";

        NewPlayerMessage.BalloonTipText = RecentPlayer + " has joined your server " + ConfigKey.ServerName.GetString();
        NewPlayerMessage.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;

    }

    private void PlayerListUpdates_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                oldCount = playerList.Items.Count - 1;
                if (oldCount < playerList.Items.Count)
                {
                    if (playerList.Items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        RecentPlayer = playerList.Items[playerList.Items.Count].ToString();

                        val = playerList.Items[playerList.Items.Count].ToString();
                        NewPlayerMessage.Visible = true;
                        SetBalloonTip();
                        NewPlayerMessage.ShowBalloonTip(50000);

                    }

                }
                else {
                    return;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** You need to remember that Array index always starts with `Zero` and ends with `Count-1`

Replace This:

```
playerList.Items[playerList.Items.Count]
```

With This:

```
playerList.Items[playerList.Items.Count-1]
```

OR

**Solution 2 :** Just use `oldCount` variable which holds the value `playerList.Items.Count - 1`

Replace This:

```
playerList.Items[playerList.Items.Count]
```

With This:

```
playerList.Items[oldCount]
```